# Not able to build labelled version of application developed using Spring-boot:

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I am getting below error when i try to build a version of my application after cutting a label,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven- 
plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default) on project quicklinks-service: RPM build 
execution returned: '1' executing '/bin/sh -c cd 
/app/jenkins_slave/workspace/SCM-quicklinks-main- 
release/service/target/rpm/quicklinks-service/SPECS && rpmbuild -bb -- 
buildroot /app/jenkins_slave/workspace/SCM-quicklinks-main- 
release/service/target/rpm/quicklinks-service/buildroot --define 
'_topdir /app/jenkins_slave/workspace/SCM-quicklinks-main- 
release/service/target/rpm/quicklinks-service' --target noarch-redhat- 
linux quicklinks-service.spec' -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone faced this issue? I tried changing the maven-release-plugin and rpm-maven-plugin with no luck.

```
Below are the environment/application details.
Java: 1.8
Maven: 3.3.9
rpm-maven-plugin: 2.0.1
maven-release-plugin: 2.5.2
maven-compiler-plugin: 3.1
Spring-boot: 2.0.4.RELEASE
Repository: Perforce
```

Comment: rpm build tools installed ? Have you check to call `rpmbuild ...`? ..

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. rpm build tools are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding copyright information under rpm-maven-plugin configuration resolved the issue.

```
<copyright>${rpm.copyright}</copyright>
```